# Continuous function and constant sign

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and $t_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f(t_0)=0$. Is it true that one can find in any case some $\epsilon >0$ such that $f$ has constant sign on $(t_0-\epsilon,t_0)$?

Answer (score 1):

No.

For example let
$$
f(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
(t-t_0)\sin\left(\frac{1}{t-t_0}\right) & \text{if} & t\ne t_0, \\
0 & \text{if} & t=t_0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$, $f(t_0)=0$, and $f$ changes sign infinitely many times in are neighborhood of $t_0$.

Comment: You beat me to it by less than one minute! My answer was almost exactly the same as yours. That just shows that this is a good example.